# Search text and copy data followed by it

Tags: excel, vba

I have one text file which contains data about list of errors.

I want to search only for ERROR word which have occurred multiple times in file and copy data quoted in '......' which is following the word ERROR=
Format is: ERROR = "short name of error.(number of words may vary,but the text following error is quoted in '...')" .

I tried this to open the file:

```
Sub FileOpenDialogBox()

Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String
Dim posLat As Integer, posLong As Integer
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", " *.txt", 1
    .Show
    fullpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
End With

End Sub
```

And to search and copy data:

```
Sub import()

Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String
Dim posLat As Integer, posLong As Integer
myFile = "fullpath"

Open myFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    text = text & textline
Loop

Close #1
posLat = InStr(text, "ERROR")
Range("A1").Value = Mid(text, posLat + 10, 5)

End Sub
```

With this script I am not able to copy each error from that text file and also data between '......' is not captured.

Can you please help me with it?

Comment: hi. should it be `myFile=fullpath`? fullPath is a variable and not a text, correct ?

Comment: yes its a variable in which selected file will be stored.

Comment: ok, so change the line to `myFile=fullpath`.  does each line contain an ERROR, or its possible that one line contains 2 ERROR ?

Comment: Thanks. Each line contains only one error.

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE***

try with this

```
Sub import()

Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String
Dim posLat As Integer, posLong As Integer, i As Long
myFile = fullpath

Open myFile For Input As #1

i = 1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    posLat = InStr(textline, "ERROR = '") + 9
    posLatFin = InStr(posLat, textline, "'")
    Cells(1, i).Value = Mid(textline, posLat, posLatFin - posLat)
    i = i + 1
Loop

Close #1
End Sub
```

***OLD***

try like this

```
Sub import()

Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String
Dim posLat As Integer, posLong As Integer, i as long
myFile = fullpath

Open myFile For Input As #1

i=1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    text = text & textline
    posLat = InStr(text, "ERROR")
    Range("A"& i ).Value = Mid(text, posLat + 10, 5)
Loop

Close #1
End Sub
```

PS: i didnt test the Mid(text, posLat + 10, 5), so i dond know exacly what happends.

Comment: thanks, there is no error after running the code. But after running there is no output.

Comment: Input:
$ information:
$ Role : component
$ Role : battery_box


ERROR = 'Some data'
$----------------------------------------------------------------------LIST

$ information:
$ Role : component
$ Role : front


ERROR = 'Some data'

$----------------------------------------------------------------------LIST


ERROR = 'Some data'
$----------------------------------------------------------------------LIST


ERROR = 'Some data'



expected output in Excel in A1,B1,C1 and so on
Some data
Some data
Some data
Some data

Thanks.